# swap images in a div for different images

Tags: jquery

basically I have 30 images in total. I would like to display all 30 images on my site however it isn't viable. So I would like to display 10 images at a time, in a .

So when the page loads the first 10 images are shown, then upon clicking a 'More' button, the next 10 are shown and upon clicking more again, the final 10 are shown. Also it could do with a previous button as well if possible!

Side note, the images are going to need to be loaded in from the JavaScript file as all 30 images loading at once is not an option!

Comment: Outstanding idea! What have your written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your image name are in alphabetical order, i.e, img1.png, img2.png ... img30.png. The below sample code will show 10 images initially, and upon the more button click, it will show another set.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pgidx = 1;
        var pgsize = 10;

        //do the initial laod
        showImage(pgidx);

        $("#more").click(function(){
            pgidx +=1;
            showImage(pgidx);
        });

        function showImage(curidx){
            var offset = (curidx-1) * pgsize;

            html = "";
            for (n=1; n<=pgsize; n++){
                html = html + '<img src="img' + (offset + n) + '.png" alt="" />';
            }

            $("#image_view").html(html);
        }



    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="image_view">
</div>
<button id="more">More</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Initially only img1 and img2 are displayed and when clicking the more button, img11 and img12 are display.

Comment: My mistake as I tested this solution with 4 images only. Change n<=2 to n<=pgsize in for loop. It shall work now.